# How to break/split the content of xmlhttp.responseText in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsa7h.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfnRq.png)

This div tag contains the following content ."Name Individual Branch"  `<div hidden name = "divT"  id = "divT" >Hi</div> <html>`
I want Name in a separate div .
These are dynamic and are coming from the database 
the following is my javascript code

```
<?php>
if ($Select=="Policy"){
$qry = "select DISTINCT l.np1_proposal POLICY , A.aag_agcode  AGENT , B.pcl_locatcode CODE , BR.pcl_locatdesc LOCATION ,p.pcl_channel CHANNEL , l.np2_setno 
  FROM lnp2_policymastr l , laag_agent A ,  pcl_complocation B , pcl_complocation BR , pcl_complocation p
  where l.np1_proposal= '$Policy' and A.aag_agcode=l.aag_agcode AND B.pcl_locatcode =A.pcl_locatcode and B.pcl_locatcode=BR.pcl_locatcode and 
   p.pcl_locatcode=BR.pcl_locatcode and l.np2_setno = (select max(np2_setno) from lnp2_policymastr where np1_proposal = '$Policy')  ";      
      $stmt = OCIParse($conn,$qry);

      OCIDefineByName($stmt,"CHANNEL",$channel); 
     OCIDefineByName($stmt,"LOCATION",$channe);       
      OCIExecute($stmt);
      OCIFETCH($stmt);
     //echo $channe;
     //OCIDefineByName($stmt,"LOCATION",$channe);  

     $q1="select  A.NPH_FULLNAME NAME , B.NPH_CODE CODE 
  FROM  lnph_pholder A , LNU1_UNDERWRITI B
  where B.NP1_PROPOSAL='$Policy' and A.NPH_CODE=B.NPH_CODE";

  $t = OCIParse($conn,$q1);

      OCIDefineByName($t,"NAME",$name); 
     //OCIDefineByName($stmt,"LOCATION",$channe);     
      OCIExecute($t);
      OCIFETCH($t);
      echo nl2br("\n$name");
      //echo $name;
// echo $_SESSION['$name'];
  }
?>
```

function showName(Policy,Select)
{

//alert("Hi"+Select+Policy);

```
if (Policy == "") {
        document.getElementById("divT").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //alert("Hi");

        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


            }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //alert("Hi3" + xmlhttp.readyState + xmlhttp.status  );

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById("divT").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("divT").style.display ='block';
                //document.getElementById("divT1").style.display ='block';
        //  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","query.php?policy="+Policy+'&select='+Select,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

```
<tr>
<td><h4>Lookup Category: * 

  <select  id= "email" name="email" style="width: 10px !important; min-width: 170px; max-width: 170px;" > 


<option value="">Please select:</option>
  <option value="Policy">Policy<p></option>
  <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
  <option value="CNIC">CNIC</option>
  <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
</select>
</td>



    <td ><div hidden name = "divT"  id = "divT" >Hi</div></td>

     <div> <span class="error"> <?php ?></div></span> 

     </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show html ?

Comment: @Lepord
the values of name ,indivual and branch are coimng from that page

Comment: if($Select =="CNIC"){

   
   $qry2="select  PCL_CHANNEL, pcl_locatdesc LOCATION from pcl_complocation where pcl_locatcode='$PCL_LOCATCODE'" ;

  $st= OCIParse($conn,$qry2);
    
   OCIDefineByName($st,"PCL_CHANNEL",$channel);  
 
   OCIExecute($st);
   OCIFETCH($st);  

   
   $query123="select APP_NAME NAME from APPLICANT WHERE APP_CNICNO='$Policy'";
   $am= OCIParse($o,$query123);
    
   OCIDefineByName($am,"NAME",$name);  
    //OCIDefineByName($am,"LOCATION",$channe);  
   OCIExecute($am);
   OCIFETCH($am); 
   echo nl2br("\n$name");
 
 }

Comment: @Leopard the above is the piece of the code

Comment: Can u please add it in question  not in comments ?

Comment: Try this `document.getElementById("divT").innerHTML`.

Comment: @Leopard ("divT" contains some text which i need to split)
how will I do that?

Comment: What text it contains ? PLease share that

Comment: it contains 
john ALI INDIVIDUAL BRANCH

Comment: It will only contain `name` ? Or is there something else in this div ?

Comment: i need to separate only the name in the div

Comment: it has three things in the div and i need to get the nane in a separate div

Comment: Than please show complete content of div otherwise how can we decide where `name` is placed in `div`. PLease show complete html of `div`

Comment: All three parts along with html like `<div>something something something</div>`

Comment: @Leopard I have posted the whole code now :)

Comment: Still i can't see the `div` you are asking for.

Comment: <div> is in the javascript code

Comment: Have you something like this `<div>something something something</div>` ? please show that

Comment: @Leopard i have added that please check now in the question :)

Comment: There is an easy way press F12 on your web page and inspect the div there you can find the html.

Comment: I have posted my whole code @Leopard there is nothing with me  now :/

Comment: I know but can u inspect the html of `div`  or can u show what is value of `xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bfnRq.png

Comment: The above is the link it has the image of what is the value of xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `innerText` adn `split` the text by word individual

```
var val = document.getElementById("divName").innerText;
val = val.split("Individual");
var name = val[0];
```

Comment: What do you mean ? You will place the code where you want tihs

Comment: I placed the code and made an alert the xmlhttp.response is the same:(

Comment: And what happened ?

Comment: I placed the code and made an alert the xmlhttp.response is the same:(

Comment: I can't say anything here can we share screen but not right now. Right now i am in office.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this piece of code and my problem was solved :P

```
            var splitResponse = xmlhttp.responseText.split( "Indiviual" );
    var firstDropdownContent = splitResponse[0];
         var secondDropdownContent = splitResponse[1];
        // var thirdDropdownContent = splitResponse[2];
             alert (firstDropdownContent);
             alert (secondDropdownContent);
             //alert (thirdDropdownContent);
```